# histogram for every variable in pandas dataframe grouped by 1 specific variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a histogram plot for every column in my pandas dataframe, but for each of the separate plots to have a separate color coding for each of the 2 values in 1 of the columns.

I can successfully create a histogram if you ignore the grouping by this field by doing

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)
random_sample_join.hist(bins=5, figsize=(20, 20), rwidth=5)
```

I tried to do it based on a grouping by adding:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)
random_sample_join.hist(bins=5, figsize=(20, 20), rwidth=5, by = 'x')
```

but I get a really weird graph for the later where nothing is eligible etc. How can I do this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)